# Custom middleware express.js framework ordering

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am writing custom middleware(s) to send request data(like request path, response code, request timestamp, etc) to a remote server on every request. I'm unable to figure out the ordering of my middlewares.

I have created 2 middlewares,
a) process_request (m1) --> this middleware just adds a timestamp to the request object to register when the request was received.
b) process_response (m2) --> this middleware posts the required data to the remote server

m1

```
function process_request(req, res, next) {
  req.requestTime = Date.now()/1000;
  next();
}
```

m2

```
function process_response(req, res, next) {
  const request_obj = {};
  request_obj.request_timestamp = req.requestTime;
  request_obj.response_timestamp = Date.now()/1000;
  request_obj.path = req.protocol + "://" + 
    req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
  request_obj.response_code = res.statusCode;
  send_perf_request(request_obj); // sends remote https request not shown here
}
```

I can think of two ordering options in my `app.js`:
Order 1:

```
m1     
route 1   
route 2    
...
route n      
m2         
404 request handler middleware
```

Order 2:

```
m1     
route 1   
route 2    
...
route n              
404 request handler middleware
m2
```

404 request handler middleware

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

The problem with `order 1` is that I won't be able to catch 404 requests, which I want to.
The problem with `order 2` in all in request the `responseCode=404` as the 404 request handler middleware is doing that.
I am new to node.js & confused if I am thinking about this the right way.

My app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

const custom_middleware = require("custom_middleware");


var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(custom_middleware.process_request);  //*calling middleware


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

//catch 404 and forward to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   console.log("in 404 handler");
//   //next(createError(404, "this page doesn't exist;"));
//   next();
// });


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // this is called only in case of errors  
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  console.log("in error handler");
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  //res.render('error');
  next(err);
});

app.use(custom_middleware.process_exception); //*calling middleware

module.exports = app;
```

Custom middleware file

```
function process_request(req, res, next) {
  // this middleware adds request timestamp
  console.log("in process request middleware");
  req.requestTime = Date.now()/1000;
  res.on("finish", function (){
        // this middleware collects performance data
        console.log("in process response middleware");
        const request_obj = {};
        request_obj.request_timestamp = req.requestTime;
        request_obj.response_timestamp = Date.now()/1000;
        request_obj.ip_address = ip.address();
        request_obj.path = req.protocol + "://" + 
        req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
        request_obj.requester = null;
        request_obj.response_code = res.statusCode;
        console.log(request_obj.response_code);
        send_perf_request(request_obj);
    })
  next();
}

function process_exception(err, req, res, next) {
  // this middleware collects exception data
  console.log("in process exception middleware");
  const error_obj = {};
  error_obj.path = req.protocol + "://" + 
    req.hostname + req.originalUrl;
  error_obj.exception = "error occured";
  error_obj.traceback = err.stack;
  error_obj.user = null;
  error_obj.ip_address = ip.address();
  send_exception_request(error_obj);
  next();
}
```

My routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  throw new Error('this does not exist'); // error manually triggered
  res.status(500);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: move away from doing in routes or attaching to a route. invoke the middleware as global `app.use (function (req, res, next) {... do something ... next()` etc then also in that middleware before next() use `res.on("finish",...` handler, which will fire when everything is done. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204192/nodejs-express-catch-the-sent-status-code-in-the-response/58205003#58205003

Comment: I do something similar to generate API documentation on the fly, which picks up all the params to/from server

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks. I will move the code of m2 inside `res.on("finish"...`. But what about the `404 handler middleware`? Should I remove that?

Comment: I would.. handle all errors in the main error handler `app.use((req, res, next, error) => {` check if its ajax with `if (req.xhr) {` respond with json else a view, you can define error from a `const err = new Error('Something not found'); err.status = 404;throw err` which would throw to a wrapping try `catch(e){next(e)}`, then the main handler pics it up.

Comment: ive answered with more details/example, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, abstract the middlewares to avoid defining a set of middlewares on each route.

To replace `m1` Create a global middleware, which you define before all your other middlewares which sets `res.on("finish", function () {})` event handler to do something when the route is done. I'm pretty sure this is the only event you will get the actual correct `res.statusCode` if you're doing `res.status()` anywhere.

Then move your 404 error handler logic into the main error handler, you can then check for status code and all that good stuff before logging and responding. You can also use req.xhr to determine how to respond.

Also, you can use a catch-all to pick up on route 404's: `app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {` then fire off an error which the error handler handles.

Here is an example putting it all together:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// logger middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  // set something
  req.requestTime = Date.now() / 1000;

  // gets fired after all routes have been handled
  res.on("finish", function () {

    //
    req.finishTime = Date.now() / 1000;

    // do something with req, res objects
    console.log('[in logger] originalUrl:', req.originalUrl)
    console.log('[in logger] status code:', res.statusCode)
  })

  next()
})

// apply routes
// ...

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // example: look for something, which is not found
    const mock = false
    if (!mock) {
      let err = new Error('Mock was not found!')
      err.status = 404
      throw err
    }

    res.send('Hello World!')
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})

// app.get('/foo', ...

// not found route (catch all)
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  let err = new Error('Page not found!')
  err.status = 404
  next(err)
})

// error handler (will catch everything even uncaught exceptions)
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {

  //
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate')
  res.header('Expires', '-1')
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache')

  // set status from error
  res.status(error.status || 500)

  if (req.xhr) {
    // is ajax call, send error as json
    res.json({
      error: error.name || 'Server error',
      status: error.status || 500,
      message: error.message || 'Internal server error'
    })
  } else {
    // render a view instead (would need to add a view engine)
    res.render('error/' + (error.status || 500), error)
  }
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('App listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lawerence This works great, but there's one issue in case of error response say 500 I am still getting 404 as the response in `res.statusCode`. The error handler is assigning 500 to the `res.status()` but somehow in `res.on("finish"..)` the status is still 404.

Comment: np, you are prob not setting `err.status = 404` somewhere and its defaulting to 500, or you have an uncaught exception which it's catching. can you put your code somewhere and ill be able to tell you for sure

Comment: in `routes/index.js` you're throwing an error, so res.status(500) is unreachable code and as said you must set the `err.status` of the error to the error code else it will do a 500 (thats what the `|| 500` are in my answer) as err.status is not in a default `new Error` object so you have to set it. Then the error handler should be setting the `res.status()` not the route middleware (as shown in my answer)

Comment: basically, throw from the route middleware and let the error handler pick it up

Comment: also as said in my answer you won't get the correct status code in the error handler so `console.log(res.statusCode);` might not be correct, the only place it will be correct is in `res.on("finish",` because its not actully set into res.statusCode from res.status(123) until way after the routes have been processed as it may need to have picked up an error from one of the middlewares, i.e i makes no sense if you set 200 and later on its boking on a logger query and causing a 500 but is still responding with a 200 so its done really late in the process.

Comment: sorry also, you have 2 final error handlers. `app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {` one and the process_exception function one. make it a single handler and handle sending the error/logger in one place. as said in my answer the main error handler will catch uncaught exceptions too. You can apply your ip_address etc there. In an app with auth its also a good idea to apply the headers to the request too if you have tokens so the auth is not lost when/if clientside you attach headers into store on each request for things like rolling auth tokens