# How to catch page not found in express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I would like to catch *404 page not found* error in express router.

I use a basic example :

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const router = express.Router();

// ROUTER MID BEFORE
router.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("Router Mid => Before"); next();});

// ROUTER PAGE /BAR
router.get('/bar', (req, res, next) => {
 console.log("Router page '/bar'");
 res.send('<body><h1>Hello World</h1></body>');
 next();
 }); 

// ROUTER NOT FOUND
router.get('*', (req, res, next) => {console.log("Router NOT FOUND"); next();});

// ROUTER MID AFTER
router.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("Router Mid => After"); next();});

// APP MID BEFORE
app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("----"); console.log("App Mid => Before"); next();});

app.use('/foo', router);

// APP NOT FOUND
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {console.log("App NOT FOUND"); next();});

// APP MID AFTER
app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("App Mid => After"); console.log("----"); next();});

app.listen(3000, () => {console.log("App Listenning")});
```

I expect the following result :

Request on **/anything**

```
----
App Mid => Before
App NOT FOUND
App Mid => After
----
```

Request on **/foo/anything**

```
----
App Mid => Before
Router Mid => Before
Router NOT FOUND
Router Mid => After
App Mid => After
----
```

Request on **/foo/bar**

```
----
App Mid => Before
Router Mid => Before
Router page '/bar'
Router Mid => After
App Mid => After
----
```

But the Not Found page are executed on every requests

For example a Request **/foo/bar** gives me :

```
----
App Mid => Before
Router Mid => Before
Router page '/bar'
Router NOT FOUND
Router Mid => After
App NOT FOUND
App Mid => After
----
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Have you tried `res.status(404)` ?

Comment: I don't understand your reply. This would change the code of my response but doesn't solve my issue (page not found call even when i found a page)

Comment: What about moving `get('*')` at the end, after trying to match all other routes? Currently it matches first, and matches everything, that's why it triggers every time

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking about, but are you just looking for [how to manage error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) in Express?

Comment: The "not found" page will execute if you keep calling `next()` on every matching route because when you call `next()` and no more routes match, then it goes to the default Express error handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to acheive that is to pass a custom flag along all the middleware.
This way i can know if a route has already send a response or if i need to send a page not found.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

// Custom not found flag setup
app.use((req, res, next) => {req.pageFound = false; next();});

// ROUTER MID BEFORE
router.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("Router Mid => Before"); next();});

// ROUTER PAGE /BAR
router.get('/bar', (req, res, next) => {
 req.pageFound = true;
 console.log("Router page '/bar'");
 res.send('<body><h1>Hello World</h1></body>');
 next();
}); 

// ROUTER NOT FOUND
router.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
 if (req.pageFound === false) { 
  req.pageFound = true;
  console.log("Router NOT FOUND");
  next();
}});

// ROUTER MID AFTER
router.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("Router Mid => After"); next();});

// APP MID BEFORE
app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("----"); console.log("App Mid => Before"); next();});

app.use('/foo', router);

// APP NOT FOUND
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
if (req.pageFound === false) {
 req.pageFound = true;
 console.log("App NOT FOUND");
 next();
}});

// APP MID AFTER
app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("App Mid => After"); console.log("----"); next();});

app.listen(3000, () => {console.log("App Listenning")});
```